# Java library to read/write Map<String, String> via bean

Tags: java

I'm looking for a library that provides type type-safe read and write access to a `Map<String, String>` via a proxied Java bean. For example:

```
interface Person {
  String getName();
  void setName(String name);
  int getAge();
  void setAge(int age);
}

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
  put("name", "juni");
  put("age", "4");
}}

Person p = HypotheticalLibrary.bind(Person.class, data);
p.getName(); // returns "juni"
p.setAge(5); // calls data.put("age", "5") --- notice the implicit type conversion
```

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one. However, it's fairly simple to write one using a [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). You would need to write an [InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) that recognises getters and setters, and gets or puts on the map accordingly. There is one fiddly bit - converting the method name to a key for the map - and one hard bit - working out how to convert the types.

I wrote a quick and dirty implementation in ~60 lines of code. It does a pretty clumsy job on the types; it would take another hundred or so to do a decent job for all basic types.

Comment: Right. This is what I was working on when I thought "surely somebody had already done this!". I was thinking that perhaps some other library could be leveraged? Perhaps something like Jackson that marshalls beans to JSON and JSON to beans. I like the idea of being able to annotate the bean with "required" and "default" values.

Comment: Fair enough. This does indeed seem like the kind of thing someone might have done before. Good luck finding it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're ok using spring as a dependency, you can use the proxy approach as suggested.  BeanUtils class takes care of turning the method name into a property descriptor so you can get the name.  No type conversion is required because you're working with the interface itself, so the compiler will ensure that you send the right type in (and thus the right type out).

```
static interface Person {
    void setName(String name);
    String getName();
    void setAge(int age);
    int getAge();
}


public static Person createPerson() {
    return createPerson(new HashMap<String, String>());
}

public static Person createPerson(final Map<String, String> props) {
    InvocationHandler ih = new InvocationHandler() {
        private TypeConverter typeConverter = new SimpleTypeConverter();

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object source, Method method, Object[] params)
                throws Throwable {
            PropertyDescriptor pd = BeanUtils.findPropertyForMethod(method);
            if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                props.put(pd.getName(), typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(params[0], String.class));
                return null;
            }
            else if (method.getName().startsWith("get") ||
                     method.getName().startsWith("is")) {
                Object res = props.get(pd.getName());
                return typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(res, method.getReturnType());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    Person p = (Person) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[] { Person.class },
            ih);

    return p;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    props.put("name", "Matt");
    props.put("age", "4");

    Person p = createPerson(props);

    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println(p.getAge());

}
```

Comment: PS:  you could of course pass the map into the createPerson method if you want to use an existing map.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate such a tidy and concise answer. Spring is absolutely acceptable. I actually need my map to be <String, String>, so I have a bit more work to do, but this is a great strategy.

Comment: I now see the type conversion issues as you want a Map<String,String> as initial input.  See my edits for updates to use the spring TypeConverter classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is one but u could build your own with the help of [mvel](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) or [ognl](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/) or [spel](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html). I did build my own sometime back.